# How to send data using different characteristic uuids in RN4871?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

We have connected RN4871 ble module to ADUCM4050 mcu through UART and want to send 2 different sensor values through bluetooth continuously. But while sending values using adi_uart_Write() through bluetooth in a loop and printing them in python(bleak) its printing 155 bytes at a time instead of printing one by one continuously.
How can we configure rn4871 so that we can receive values one bye one
and Can we send values using two different characteristic uuids? If yes,can anyone tell how?

We tried by sending 2 sensor values separately and in python written code for dividing whole 155 byte array into 2 or 4bytes of our requirement.